# Multipart Video Upload from iOS takes too long. The same video posted from android is fine

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to upload a video file from multipart upload, what happens is the video takes a long time(3.5 minutes) to be submitted. The file size is max around 18 to 20 mb. Also if a video is submitted in parallel from a different device simultaneously then the upload is stuck forever. I have given my code below.

```
var url = ""
switch tag {
case "video":
    url = "fall_risk"
default:
    return
}
let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
var request = createRequest(method: "POST", contentType:"multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", endPoint: "mobile/visits/\(visitId)/\(url)")

//let compressionQuality : CGFloat = 0.5

let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
request.httpBody = createBody(parameters: parameters,
                                boundary: boundary,
                                data: videoData as Data,
                                mimeType: "video/mov",
                                filename: "\(filename)\(visitId).mov")

print("this is the video file name ::::",filename)
print("Create Image: \(String(describing: request.url!.absoluteString))")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    self.hideProgressSpinner()
    guard error == nil else {
        // handle error here
        print(error!)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5), execute: {
            postVideoForPatient(visitId: visitId, tag: tag, videoData: videoData, parameters: parameters, completionHandler: completionHandler)  ////Call the method for video upload again in case of error occurred.
        })
        return
    }
    do {
        _ = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebServiceResponseCommon.self, from: data!)
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    catch {
        print("createImage Error: \(error)")
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
task.resume()
}
```